# How do I display a confirmation snackbar on the Scaffold only on a success callback from Firebase?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, mobile, dart

This is a dialog to reset a forgotten password through Firebase. I want to display an error message from Firebase if there is one, then dismiss the `forgotPassword` dialog and display a confirmation Snackbar on the Scaffold on success. I can't figure out how to display the snackbar ONLY on a success callback from Firebase.

This is onPressed method for the `forgotPassword` dialog:

```
onPressed: () {
  if (_resetPasswordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    widget.auth.resetPassword(_resetPasswordController.text)
      ..catchError((e) {
        _buildErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
        return;
        }).then((_) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('PASSWORD RESET EMAIL SENT'),
                ),
                  );
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          });
        }
       }
```

I know I'm misunderstanding the usage of the catchError callback...

For reference, here is the resetPassword method:

```
Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async =>
      await _firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
```

As is everything works except the snackbar on the Scaffold - it doesn't display on success - the dialog just gets dismissed and that's it.

[image: forgotPasswordDialog]
[image: error from Firebase]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Does the snackbar display if you do not call pop on the navigator?

Comment: @SamJakob it doesn't. I have the same problem with the snackbar not displaying, even tried using the global _loginScreenKey to call it. I can't figure out where to put the code I want executed on success (display snackbar and close dialog)

Comment: Did you got any error messages while using `ScaffoldState` globalkey to display your snackbar? @Garrison

Comment: @HasilT I have changed it to use the _loginScreenKey and now it displays, but it does so everytime even when an error is present and doesn't close the dialog

Comment: @Garrison I believe that may be because the error is being caught in `.catchError` and then the `.then` callback is being executed. Try moving `.catchError` (with a single period) to after `.then`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using a simple try catch block instead then calling the snackbar using _loginScreenKey global key.

```
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_resetPasswordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                        try {
                          await widget.auth
                              .resetPassword(_resetPasswordController.text);
                        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
                          await _buildErrorDialog(context, e.message);
                          return;
                        }
                        _loginScaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text('PASSWORD RESET EMAIL SENT'),
                          ),
                        );
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

> As is everything works except the snackbar on the Scaffold - it doesn't display on success - the dialog just gets dismissed and that's it.

In this case it's because the `BuildContext` used in the method

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(...)
```

has no `Scaffold` widget as a parent. Meaning you need a `BuildContext` inside the `Scaffold` widget tree since you return `Scaffold` in the function

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
```

- A solution here is to wrap the button widget with a `Builder` widget that has a context that refers to the parent `Scaffold`. Check out this explanation from Flutter's documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html#material.Scaffold.of.2
- Another approach is to split the button widget to its own `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` like so:

```dart
class SeparateButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
      onPressed: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Success/Fail message...'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

- Using `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>()` is the least recommended approach because Global keys are expensive according to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html